# exec() bytecode with arbitrary locals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode, codeblocks

Suppose I want to execute code, for example

```
    value += 5
```

inside a namespace of my own (so the result is essentially `mydict['value'] += 5`). There's a function `exec()`, but I have to pass a string there:

```
    exec('value += 5', mydict)
```

and passing statements as strings seems strange (e.g. it's not colorized that way). 
Can it be done like:

```
    def block():
        value += 5

    ???(block, mydict)
```

? The obvious candidate for last line was `exec(block.__code__, mydict)`, but no luck: it raises `UnboundLocalError` about `value`. I believe it basically executes `block()`, not *the code inside block*, so assignments aren't easy – is that correct?

Of course, another possible solution would be to disassembly `block.__code__`...

FYI, I got the question because of [this thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-August/005552.html). Also, this is why some (me undecided) call for new syntax

```
    using mydict: 
        value += 5
```

---

Note how this doesn't throw error but doesn't change `mydict` either:

```
    def block(value = 0):
        value += 5

    block(**mydict)
```

Comment: What's wrong with simple class definitions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about classes. I'll try to post an answer outlining one possible idea you might mean, but feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass bytecode instead of a string to `exec`, you just need to make the right bytecode for the purpose:

```
>>> bytecode = compile('value += 5', '<string>', 'exec')
>>> mydict = {'value': 23}
>>> exec(bytecode, mydict)
>>> mydict['value']
28
```

Specifically, ...:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(bytecode)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (value)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_NAME               0 (value)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

the load and store instructions must be of the _NAME persuasion, and this `compile` makes them so, while...:

```
>>> def f(): value += 5
... 
>>> dis.dis(f.func_code)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (value)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              6 INPLACE_ADD         
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (value)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

...code in a function is optimized to use the _FAST versions, and those don't work on a dict passed to `exec`.  If you started somehow with a bytecode using the _FAST instructions, you could patch it to use the _NAME kind instead, e.g. with [bytecodehacks](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-announce-list/2004-July/003280.html) or some similar approach.

Comment: It looks like hacking the bytecode is a good idea in this case, especially since the semantics of what I want, function `apply_code_to_dict` is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `global` keyword to force dynamic scoping on any variables you want to modify from within the block:

```
def block():
    global value
    value += 5

mydict = {"value": 42}
exec(block.__code__, mydict)
print(mydict["value"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a crazy decorator to create such a block that uses "custom locals". In reality it is a quick hack to turn all variable access inside the function to global access, and evaluate the result with the custom locals dictionary as environment.

```
import dis
import functools
import types
import string

def withlocals(func):
    """Decorator for executing a block with custom "local" variables.

    The decorated function takes one argument: its scope dictionary.

    >>> @withlocals
    ... def block():
    ...     counter += 1
    ...     luckynumber = 88

    >>> d = {"counter": 1}
    >>> block(d)
    >>> d["counter"]
    2
    >>> d["luckynumber"]
    88
    """
    def opstr(*opnames):
        return "".join([chr(dis.opmap[N]) for N in opnames])

    translation_table = string.maketrans(
            opstr("LOAD_FAST", "STORE_FAST"),
            opstr("LOAD_GLOBAL", "STORE_GLOBAL"))

    c = func.func_code
    newcode = types.CodeType(c.co_argcount,
                             0, # co_nlocals
                             c.co_stacksize,
                             c.co_flags,
                             c.co_code.translate(translation_table),
                             c.co_consts,
                             c.co_varnames, # co_names, name of global vars
                             (), # co_varnames
                             c.co_filename,
                             c.co_name,
                             c.co_firstlineno,
                             c.co_lnotab)

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(mylocals):
        return eval(newcode, mylocals)
    return wrapper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

This is just a monkey-patching adaption of someone's brilliant recipe for a [goto decorator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576944/)

Comment: rather than a decorator, more sane use might be making it just a function call `withlocals(block, d)`

Comment: thanks. I suspect Martelli knows much more about this than me though, I just managed to throw together something that "works" (ashamed to call it working).. maybe `LOAD_NAME` is better than `LOAD_GLOBAL`?

Answer (score 0):

From S.Lott's comment above I think I get the idea for an answer using creation of new class.

```
class _(__metaclass__ = change(mydict)):
    value += 1
    ...
```

where `change` is a metaclass whose `__prepare__` reads dictionary and whose `__new__` updates dictionary.

For reuse, the snippet below would work, but it's kind of ugly:

```
def increase_value(d):
    class _(__metaclass__ = change(d)):
        value += 1
        ...

increase_value(mydict)
```